# httperf benchmarking for file upload using POST

Tags: benchmarking, httperf

I want to benchmark uploading of files to a remote server using HTTPERF

I know that there is a wsesslog option where I can give entries for form data.

But can I send a post request for a file as well?

something like:

> httperf --hog --server 127.0.0.1 --port 5000
>   --add-header="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n"   --wsesslog=150,0,httperf_content

httperf_content file contains

```
/ method=POST contents="file=PATH_TO_FILE"
```

Comment: Did you find any solution eventually? @Akshya11235